# How do I add values to semi-complex JSON object?

Tags: javascript, json, object, addition

I'm fairly new to using JSON objects and I'm kinda stuck.

I've got an JSON object that was converted from this array:

```
Array
(
    [status] => success
    [id] => 1
    [name] => Zone 1
    [description] => Awesome zone deze..
    [tiles] => Array
    (
        // Column for the tile grid
        [0] => Array
            (
                // Row for the tile grid
                [0] => Array
                    (
                        [tileID] => 1
                        [rotation] => 0
                    )
                [1] => Array
                    (
                        [tileID] => 1
                        [rotation] => 0
                    )
                // Etc..
            )
        [1] => Array // etc.. etc..
    )
)
```

I use this object to render out an isometric grid for my HTML5 Canvas game. I'm building a map editor and to put more tiles on the map, i'll have to add values to this json object.

This is how I would do it in PHP:

```
mapData[column][row] = array(
    'tileID' => 1,
    'rotation' => 0
);
```

So my question is, how do I achieve this with a JSON object in javascript?

Thanks in advance!

Nick

**Update**

I've ran into an error:

```
can't convert undefined to object
mapDataTiles[mouseY][mouseX] = { tileID: editorSelectedTile, rotation: 0 };
```

This is the code i use for clicking & then saving the new tile to the JSON object. At first I though that one of my parameters was 'undefined', so i logged those to the console but they came out perfectly..

```
// If there is already a tile placed on these coordinates
if( mapDataTiles[mouseX] && mapDataTiles[mouseX][mouseY] )
{
    mapDataTiles[mouseX][mouseY]['tileID'] = editorSelectedTile;
}
// If there is no tile placed on these coordinates
else
{
    mapDataTiles[mouseX][mouseY] = { tileID: editorSelectedTile, rotation: 0 };
}
```

My variables have the following values:

```
MouseX: 5
MouseY: 17 
tileID: 2
```

Also weird fact, that for some coordinates it does actually work and save new data to the array.

**UPDATE 2**

After a couple of hours of trial and error coding I've come up with a solution!

Thanks for everyone's help anyway!

If anyone is curious, ill be happy to show my code. What I've got so far is the ability to expand the world map in any direction for an unlimited amount of tiles. :D

Cya

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well pretty much the same way. A JavaScript object is one of the simplest things to alterate :)

```
jsonObject.tiles[column][row] = {tileID: 1, rotation: 0};
```

Comment: I've tried that but I'm getting a weird error, see above. Thanks for answering so fast though!

Comment: You have to make sure that the column or row arrays actually exists - They're not created dynamically. You should change your "else" clause to check for the array existence, and if it doesn't exist, then create an array at the given column/row.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add a row :

```
mapData.tiles.push([
{
    'tileID': 1,
    'rotation': 0
},
{
    'tileID': 3,
    'rotation': 0
}]);
```

If you want to add a column to an existing row:

```
mapData.tiles[row].push({
    'tileID': 1,
    'rotation': 0
});
```

Comment: But if I do it like that I have no control over the 'column' anymore, and that's vital. Right?

Comment: That's the way to create rows and columns.
To access them, use the Saebekassebil's method.

Comment: No you don't get what I mean. If I do it like that "mapData.tiles[row].push(.." I have no control over the [col] key, which is vital. If I do it like that it will just add one column and give it an index based on its predececors. I eventually did it like this: mapData[row] = new Array(); mapData[row][col] = { tileID: 1 }